# sympy hangs when trying to solve a simple algebraic equation

Tags: python, solver, sympy, exp

I recently reinstalled my python environment and a code that used to work very quickly now creeps at best (usually just hangs taking up more and more memory).

The point at which the code hangs is:

```
solve(exp(-alpha * x**2) - 0.01, alpha)
```

I've been able to reproduce this problem with a fresh IPython 0.13.1 session:

```
In [1]: from sympy import solve, Symbol, exp
In [2]: x = 14.7296138519
In [3]: alpha = Symbol('alpha', real=True)
In [4]: solve(exp(-alpha * x**2) - 0.01, alpha)
```

this works for integers but also quite slow. In the original code I looped over this looking for hundreds of different alpha's for different values of x (other than 14.7296138519) and it didn't take more than a second.

any thoughts?

Comment: What is your `sympy.__version__`?

Comment: I have '0.7.1.rc1' and it solves instantly. Perhaps there is a regression

Comment: interesting, I suspected that the reinstallation of my python env had something to do with it. I'll roll back to your version and report in a sec.

Comment: `easy_install sympy==0.7.1` did it! I've reported this as a bug to sympy's google code. Thanks!

Comment: Still the same problem in 3.9. [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17114550/774575) works.

Answer (score 5):

The rational=False flag was introduced for such cases as this.

```
>>> q=14.7296138519
>>> solve(exp(-alpha * q**2) - 0.01, alpha, rational=False)
[0.0212257459123917]
```

(The explanation is given in the issue cited above.)

Comment: Someone should mark this as correct. Based on rep, I'd guess @Shahar won't notice this so maybe a moderator can?

Comment: This parameter allows solving equations like e^(-at)=k which otherwise hang the kernel in version 3.9. Looks like this answer should be selected.

Answer (score 2):

Rolling back from version 0.7.2 to 0.7.1 solved this problem.

```
easy_install sympy==0.7.1
```

I've reported this as a bug to sympy's google code.

Answer (score 0):

I am currently running `sympy` ver: 1.11.1
This is for all I know the latest version.
However, hanging as was described, when solving a set of 3 differential for 3 angular double differentials persist.

Eg.:

```
sols = solve([LE1, LE2, LE3], (the_dd, phi_dd, psi_dd),
             simplify=False, rational=False)
```