# sympy - symbolically solve equations with float power

Tags: python, sympy

Using sympy, I define the symbols,

```
a, b, c = sympy.symbols(['a', 'b', 'c'])
```

Then, when I try to solve the following system of equations,

```
sympy.solve([sympy.Eq(b - a**2.552 - c), sympy.Eq(a, 2)])
```

I get the solution,

```
[{b: c + 5.86446702875684, a: 2.00000000000000}]
```

But, when I try to solve,

```
sympy.solve([sympy.Eq(b - a**2.552 - c), sympy.Eq(b, 2)])
```

It just seems to keep running (for ~4hrs), with no solution. Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't know why but `rational=False` helps

```
sympy.solve([sympy.Eq(b - a**2.552 - c), sympy.Eq(b, 2)], rational=False)
```

see: [sympy hangs when trying to solve a simple algebraic equation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17087629/sympy-hangs-when-trying-to-solve-a-simple-algebraic-equation)

Comment: Floating point powers are converted to rational powers, which can result in polynomials of enormous degree.